# Resolve array of promises one after another

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I've found lots of solutions for this, typically something like

```
const serial = funcs =>
  funcs.reduce((promise, func) =>
    promise.then(result =>
      func().then(Array.prototype.concat.bind(result))),
  Promise.resolve([])
  )
```

I'm trying to map an array of promises and run them one after another,

```
 serial(Object.keys(tables).map(key => 
 websocketExecute(store,dropTableSQL(tables[key]),null)))
 .then(data => {console.log(data);success(data)})
```

They all run however I get an error `TypeError: func is not a function`

And the final then isn't resolved..

Any idea how I run a final .then() on a list of promises?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function `serial` expects its argument to be an array of functions that return Promises

however,

```
Object.keys(tables).map(key => websocketExecute(store,dropTableSQL(tables[key]),null))
```

returns an array of the results of calling

```
websocketExecute(store,dropTableSQL(tables[key]),null)
```

Which is not likely to be a function returning a promise, more like some result

What you'll want to do is:

```
serial(Object.keys(tables).map(key => () => websocketExecute(store,dropTableSQL(tables[key]),null)))
.then(data => {console.log(data);success(data)})
```

Assuming `websocketExecute` returns a Promise

So now, the array returned by `.map` is an array of

```
() => websocketExecute(store,dropTableSQL(tables[key]),null)
```

Which will get called in turn in `.reduce`

Comment: you are awesome

Comment: @user5839 - in your `serial` function, can't you change `Array.prototype.concat.bind(result)` to `result.concat.bind(result)` as well?

Answer (score -1):

Check out [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) as well.

If I'm not mistaken, you should be able to do something like the following:

```
const promises: Promise<any>[] = Object.keys(tables).map(key => (
    websocketExecute(store, dropTableSQL(tables[key]), null)
)

Promise.all(promises).then((results: any[]) => { ...do stuff })
```

Typescript annotations are for readability.

Comment: The original code is required to run each function in series - yours does it in parallel

Comment: Gotcha, simple oversight.